# Abstract vs Natural model - which one do I choose?

Tags: predicate-logic, model-theory

I have the problem described below:
**Describe the model such that `∀x∀y (A(x,y) → x ≠ y)` is false.**
Does anyone have any hints on how to solve this problem?
I know that it is possible to solve this type of problem with an abstract model and a natural model,
which one do I chose?

Comment: apologies for my ignorance, but what are "abstract" and "natural" models? (do you have a reference for these terms?)

Comment: (I may be misunderstanding the question, but are you just looking for an $\{A\}$-structure in which the given sentence is false, where $A$ is a two-ary relation? in that case you can, eg, just take any set and let $A$ to be any reflexive relation. for instance, let the universe be $\{\star\}$ and let $A$ be equality. can you see why $\forall x\forall y(A(x,y)\to x\neq y)$ does not hold in this structure?)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom , I actually chose my universe to be all natural numbers, then I defined A to be x = y, I got 1 = 1 → 1 ≠ 1, In other words I got True → False, which is false, is this a correct way to solve the problem?:)

Comment: yep, that works! :)

Comment: Then what will my conclusion/answer be? can I say "It exists an x and a y such that ∀x∀y(A(x,y)→x≠y) is false ? :)

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom, Also, I think that your approach is a natural model, and the approach that Gregory Nisbet did (se answer below) is an abstract model.

Comment: this is a bit pedantic but not *quite* – you want to say that there exist assigments of $x$ and $y$ such that the *formula* $A(x,y)\to x\neq y$ is false, and so in particular the *sentence* $\forall x\forall yA(x,y)\to x\neq y$ is false. does that make sense? the reason is that the sentence $\forall x\forall yA(x,y)\to x\neq y$ does not contain $x$ and $y$ as free variables, so it doesn't entirely make sense to talk about its truth value as being related to a particular choice for $x$ and $y$. but the spirit of what you have is completely right!

Comment: (p.s. apologies, but I still don't quite understand what you mean by natural and abstract models; my example and Gregory Nisbet's are in fact "isomorphic", so they are thought of as having all the same "model-theoretic" properties. do you perhaps have lectures notes or a textbook in which those terms have been defined? just as an fyi, I think they are non-standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a worked example that spells everything out. Please think about each step with some skepticism.

Try negating the sentence in first order logic and then take a look at it and see if any strategies for producing a model jump out.

$$ \forall x \forall y \mathop. A(x, y) \to x \ne y $$

rewrite in negative normal form

$$ \forall x \forall y \mathop. \lnot A(x, y) \lor x \ne y $$

negates to

$$ \exists c \exists d \mathop. A(c, d) \land c = d $$

We can skolemize (trivially), producing an equisatisfiable theory.

$$ A(c, d) \land c = d $$

So

$$ A(c,d) \;\;\text{and}\;\; c = d $$

So

$$ A(c, c) $$

So, if we pick $\{c\}$ as our domain of discourse and pick $\{(c, c)\}$ as our interpretation of $A$, we now have a model in which $\forall x \forall y \mathop. A(x, y) \to x \ne y $.

In order to check, note that our domain has a single element $c$.

$$ A(c, c) \to c \ne c $$
$$ \top \to \bot $$
$$ \bot $$

Therefore the original sentence is indeed false as desired.

Comment: Really nice explanation, but I want ∀x∀y.A(x,y)→x≠y to be false, I think you show when it is true? am I wrong?:)

Comment: @AugustJelemson It's false in this model. In one of the steps I negated the formula by replacing all the connectives, quantifiers, and literals.

Comment: Thanks :) , what is the universe in your proof? is c the universe? :)

Comment: @AugustJelemson Yes. $\{c\}$ is the universe. It's also the interpretation of $A$.

Comment: p.s. this is a pedantic point, but $A$ is a two-ary relation, not a one-ary relation, so to be precise its interpretation should be a set of ordered *pairs* of elements of the structure, not a set of individual elements of the structure. in particular, the interpretation of $A$ in your structure is $\{(c,c)\}$, and not $\{c\}$. hopefully that makes sense :)

Comment: @AugustJelemson, Atticus Sonestrom is correct. $A$ is a two-place relation and thus has $\{(c, c)\}$ as its interpretation. That's an important point.